# How to Concatenate multiple pandas dataframes. names of these dataframe are saved in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, concatenation

How do i concatenate data frames from a list called 'df_list' containing names of pandas dataframes?
the list is generated through a looping process.

```
df_list = ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3']

xyz=pd.concat((x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3), axis=0)
xyz
```

I can always concatenate it like as above manually. However since the number of dataframes can increase or decrease in an automated process. How do i dynamically use this list with concat function?

This doesnt work =>    `xyz=pd.concat((df_list ), axis=0)`

Tried converting df_list to series but that also doesnt work.

I am a beginner. any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `xyz=pd.concat(df_list , axis=0)`

Comment: this isnt working. I believe since it is stored as string in the df_list. 

TypeError: cannot concatenate object of type '<class 'str'>'; only Series and DataFrame objs are valid

Comment: I see, you need `df_list  = [x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]`, list of DataFrames, not list of strings

Comment: yes and i am not able to figure out how to achieve this df_list  = [x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3]

Comment: Use `xyz=pd.concat(df_list , axis=0)`

Comment: Error mean `df_list = ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3']` are not DataFrames, by strings, so expected.

Comment: xyz=pd.concat(df_list , axis=0)
this is not working 

How to convert 
df_list = ['x_0', 'x_1', 'x_2', 'x_3']

to 

df_list = [x_0, x_1, x_2, x_3] ?

df_list is dynamically generated through a loop process. and x_0, x_1 are dataframes. Since it is part of list. the names are in string format.

Btw i see question has been wrongly closed by stack overflow.. how do i reopen.